# .Net MemberwiseClone vs Java Clone

Tags: c#, java, .net

I'm converting C# code  to Java. There are many different places  that relies on [.Net MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) in the code I'm converting.

It seems that they both make shallow copy. So is it possible to simply replace these calls with Java's [`clone()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)? I want to make sure there are not any minor differences that would cause difficult to fix bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the `clone()` call in Java is *just* calling the `Object.clone()` implementation, then I believe they have the same behaviour:

- Another object of the same class is created
- The fields are copied (up and down the inheritance hierarchy)
- All copies are performed in a shallow way
- No user-specified code is executed (constructors etc)